# Vertically aligned text clumps together as height of viewport decreases

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmYZoJ

Using Foundation CSS Framework

Made landing page

Landing page is 100% height of any device: ie : html, body, landing-page height:100%

Added text in landing page

Text is vertically centered with position: absolute with top: %;

Problem : As the height of the viewport gets smaller my text gets clumped.

**My goal is to have a responsive landing page for all heights and widths**

**My solution to the problem?**: When text clumps up, make a max-height media query and reposition the text by changing the top: % of the the text. But a problem with this is what if there are devices that are these resolutions:

300 x 300

400 x 300

500 x 300

Currently I have media queries that increase the font-size of text as the width increase.

[Example Only] media min-width(40em) media min-width(100em)

But what if the device width increases and the height remains the same? This would make my text overlap because the font-size gets bigger but the height of is still the same.

```
 <!-- Background --> 
 <div class="row column landing-bg">

    <!-- Info -->
     <h2 class="name">John Star</h2>
     <h3 class="role">Web Developer</h3>
    <!-- Info --> 

 </div>
 <!-- Background -->
```

> 

```
/************************************
Global
************************************/

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    max-width: none;
}

/************************************
LANDING PAGE
************************************/

/* Background */
.landing-bg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background: url("https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/KADOHF81P4.jpg");
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 70%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Info */
.name, .role {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
.name {
    top: 45%;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.7rem;
}
.role {
    top: 53%;
    color: #3687be;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, Varin and I left the same answer, but Varin answered about 6 minutes after I did. It helps the community if you select the most helpful answer, and if there are multiple answers that are the same, select the first one. Some people who answer may just copy someone else's answer, and the same exact answer isn't helpful if it's left more than once - it helps if we don't reward people who may be doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your text in an absolutely positioned div instead of absolutely positioning the h2 and h3 tags. Check this out:

```
 <div class="row column landing-bg">

    <!-- Info -->
 <div class="bishment">
       <h2 class="name">John Star</h2>
       <h3 class="role">Web Developer</h3>
 </div>
    <!-- Info --> 

 </div>



.bishment {
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbwMLE

Comment: thanks, i notice that if i take the transform out. the top 50% doesnt vertically center . i have to put it to top 43%. Why is that?

Comment: You should always use transform when repositioning this way. Using just 'top' will position the did relative to its corner, not its center

Answer (score 0):

I would put them in a parent element, then position the parent element instead.

```css
/************************************
Global
************************************/

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.row {
 max-width: none;
}

/************************************
LANDING PAGE
************************************/

/* Background */
.landing-bg {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 background: url("https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/KADOHF81P4.jpg");
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: 0 70%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Info */
.name, .role {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
.name {
 color: #fff;
 letter-spacing: 0.7rem;
}
.role {
 color: #3687be;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-family: monospace;
}
.nameHead {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.0.5/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin+Dark" rel="stylesheet">


<!--LANDING PAGE-->

<!-- Background -->
<div class="row column landing-bg">

  <!-- Info -->
  <header class="nameHead">
    <h2 class="name">John Star</h2>
    <h3 class="role">Web Developer</h3>
  </header>
  <!-- Info -->

</div>
<!-- Background -->

<!--LANDING PAGE-->
```